# Convert xcom_pull list in the "in" clause of SQL query

Tags: airflow, postgres-operator

I am using Apache Airflow with a DAG with 2 tasks.

Task 1 pulls a list of ids using a `SELECT` query, and sets the result using `xcom_push`.

Task 2 needs to `xcom_pull` that list and convert it to a comma-separated string and use that in an `IN` clause of an `UPDATE` query. I am however unable to parse this list returned by `xcom_pull` using

```
join(map(str, "{{xcom_pull(key='file_ids_to_update'}}"))
```

Looking for help regarding how do I convert a list returned using `xcom_pull` and convert it to a comma separated list of ids

I want to use `xcom_pull` and parse its response as a comma:

```
def get_processed_files(ti):
    sql = "select id from files where status='DONE'"
    pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="conn_id")
    connection = pg_hook.get_conn()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    files = cursor.fetchall()
    ti.xcom_push(key="file_ids_to_update", value=files)

archive_file = PostgresOperator(task_id="archive_processed_file", postgres_conn_id="upflow",
                                sql="update files set update_date=now() where id in (%(list_of_ids)s)",
                                parameters={"list_of_ids": ",".join(map(str, "{{ti.xcom_pull(key='file_ids_to_update')}}"))})
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the method `join` should be inside your jinja template, where you want to apply it on the result of `xcom_pull` during the run_time and not on the string of your jinja template:

```py
parameters={"list_of_ids": "{{ ','.join(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='file_ids_to_update')) }}"}
```

Here is an example which can help you to debug and easily test the method:

```py
with DAG(
        'read_and_parse_xcom',
        start_date=datetime(2022, 8, 26)
) as dag:
    task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="t1",
        python_callable=lambda: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
    )

    task2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t2",
        bash_command="echo {{ ','.join(ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='t1')) }}"
    )

    task1 >> task2
```